# Cannot install setuptools

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm

I am getting "python packaging tools not found" error in pycharm. 
When I try to update the setuptools by following command

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

I get following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                        File "D:\FSM-Logistic\QGISAPI\apps\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main                               "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)                                                                                  File "D:\FSM-Logistic\QGISAPI\apps\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code                                          exec code in run_globals
  File "c:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "D:\FSM-Logistic\QGISAPI\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>                      from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog                                                           File "D:\FSM-Logistic\QGISAPI\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>                from pip._vendor import pkg_resources
  File "D:\FSM-Logistic\QGISAPI\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 73, in <module>                                                                                                                        __import__('pip._vendor.packaging.specifiers')
  File "D:\FSM-Logistic\QGISAPI\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\packaging\specifiers.py", line 275, in <module>                                                                                                                         class Specifier(_IndividualSpecifier):                                                                                File "D:\FSM-Logistic\QGISAPI\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\packaging\specifiers.py", line 373, in Specifier
    r"^\s*" + _regex_str + r"\s*$", re.VERBOSE | re.IGNORECASE)
  File "D:\FSM-Logistic\QGISAPI\apps\Python27\lib\re.py", line 190, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "D:\FSM-Logistic\QGISAPI\apps\Python27\lib\re.py", line 242, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat
```

Why my package is showing empty even i give correct path for project interpreter
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct environment in Pycharm?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid you mean which one. I try to put project interpreter as python.exe path

Comment: exit from pycharm go to project folder delete `venv` folder and then again open project folder in pycharm and set interpreter again and apply. Then go to file ---> setting --> python interpreter --> + and search for setuptools . It may work.

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare i could not find venv folder  and i have tried from setting for project interpreter. I get either Non-zero exit code(4) or previouis error

Comment: Means interpreter and virtual environment is not yet setup for your project.

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare yes i am not using virtual env for this project

Comment: whenever you setup interpreter it automatically creates virtual env for you and then all packages will get install in same environment and every scripts of your project runs in same environment .

Comment: Install `pip` first for the version of python you are using.